# hadoop build from source error on hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient

Tags: maven, hadoop

I tried to build hadoop-2.3.0 from source. I caught some errors but I cannot resolve the problem below..

Is there someone who can help me? Follwings are my environment

```
ubuntu 12.04.04 LTS (64bit)
maven version 3.0.4
JAVA version 1.6.0_45
protoc version 2.5.0
cmake version 2.8.7
zlib1g-dev, libssl-dev are installed
```

Since I want to show you the whole error messages, I added -e and -X on command

$ mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar -e -X

Followings are the whole error message

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ SUCCESS [2.137s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM ......................... SUCCESS [1.512s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations ......................... SUCCESS [2.704s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies .......................... SUCCESS [0.581s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM .................... SUCCESS [2.218s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ....................... SUCCESS [3.865s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC ............................. SUCCESS [2.804s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................ SUCCESS [3.109s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ....................... SUCCESS [2.645s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common .............................. SUCCESS [1:29.239s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS ................................. SUCCESS [7.939s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ...................... SUCCESS [0.071s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................ SUCCESS [1:35.725s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS .............................. SUCCESS [19.473s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal ............. SUCCESS [6.989s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................ SUCCESS [4.419s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ........................ SUCCESS [0.072s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn ....................................... SUCCESS [0.045s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-api ................................... SUCCESS [58.260s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-common ................................ SUCCESS [25.479s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server ................................ SUCCESS [0.130s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-common ......................... SUCCESS [8.548s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager .................... SUCCESS [12.167s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy ...................... SUCCESS [2.474s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager ................ SUCCESS [10.978s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-tests .......................... SUCCESS [0.468s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-client ................................ SUCCESS [3.770s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications .......................... SUCCESS [0.042s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell ......... SUCCESS [2.034s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher .... SUCCESS [1.882s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-site .................................. SUCCESS [0.059s]
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-project ............................... SUCCESS [4.185s]
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client ........................... SUCCESS [0.109s]
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-core ...................... SUCCESS [16.452s]
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-common .................... SUCCESS [18.989s]
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle ................... SUCCESS [2.594s]
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-app ....................... SUCCESS [8.025s]
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs ........................ SUCCESS [7.657s]
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient ................. FAILURE [2:08.027s]
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9:21.389s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 10 17:04:43 KST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 67M/397M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.3.0: Could not transfer artifact org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.0.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.0.0/hsqldb-2.0.0.jar from central failed: Read timed out -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.3.0: Could not transfer artifact org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.0.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.0.0/hsqldb-2.0.0.jar from central failed
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.3.0: Could not transfer artifact org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.0.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.0.0/hsqldb-2.0.0.jar from central failed
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.0.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.0.0/hsqldb-2.0.0.jar from central failed
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:183)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.0.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.0.0/hsqldb-2.0.0.jar from central failed
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.0.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.0.0/hsqldb-2.0.0.jar from central failed
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.0.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.0.0/hsqldb-2.0.0.jar from central failed
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:939)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: GET request of: org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.0.0/hsqldb-2.0.0.jar from central failed
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:338)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:276)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:170)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:328)
    ... 9 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I really hope you can help me.
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

It must be temporary network error. Have you tried again?

This jar file exists: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.0.0/hsqldb-2.0.0.jar